# web api not get called from windows phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, async-await, asp.net-web-api2

**Problem:** `Web-api` calls are not working when application is live on store, everything works fine at debug time. I do not know where the problem is ?

**One of the calls include:**

```
    private void btn_Tap(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        var clt = new WebClient();
        clt.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
        string st = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new EmlMsg { BodyText = "dummy mail" });
        clt.UploadStringAsync(new Uri("http://example.com/api/mail", UriKind.Absolute), st);
    }
```

**Note:** Apllication has lots of async and await calls.

**What I have Tried:**

- Used HttpClient to send request, but problem is same.
- Applied logs on web-api, request didn't reached there.
- Published a beta app with this functionality, worked fine on live.
- Have tested web-api with fiddler, worked fine.
- These calls used to work on earlier versions.

**Update 1:**

I found *Security Error* message in *completed* event handler of this call. For this I have tried to add this *clientaccesspolicy.xml* file at root of my web-api, seems not worked as problem is same.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<access-policy>
    <cross-domain-access>
        <policy>
            <allow-from http-request-headers="*">
              <!--<allow-from http-request-headers="SOAPAction">-->
                <domain uri="*"/>
            </allow-from>
            <grant-to>
                <resource path="/" include-subpaths="true"/>
            </grant-to>
        </policy>
    </cross-domain-access>
</access-policy>
```

Comment: Have you tried making your method `async` and `await`ing the call to `clt.UploadStringAsync`?

Comment: Do you control the server? Do he calls reach the server?

Comment: @Paulo Yes, I have server access and calls didn't reach there.

Comment: @Daniel: I have tried that it didn't work. Actually clt.UploadStringAsync method returns void So, we can't await that, I used HttpClient for this, same problem.

Comment: To `WebClient.UploadStringAsync` is event based. To use `async-await` you need to use `WebClient.UploadStringTaskAsync. But this is starting to look like it's not related to `web-api` or `async-await`. Can you navigate to that URL on the browser?

Comment: @Paulo: URL is of web api, it has no UI.

Comment: It's an URL. The browser will make a GET request. What happens next depends on the browser and the content type.

Comment: @Paulo: Absolutly dear, but our web api has POST methods (no GET)

Comment: @Dev, you do understand that I'm trying to determine if the device can reach the server, right? The browser is just a way to reach the server. The first test is not about application protocols. Just networking.

Comment: @Paulo: I have tested web-api with fiddler, it worked fine there.

Comment: check out update, may be it have a clue.